# tkinter: Is it possible to connect 2 frames with a line?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

With tkinter i'm trying to build a simple GUI. but I ran into a problem.

I have 2 canvas, see the red and green squares, on a bigger canvas. I want to visually connect the 2 canvas with eachother with a line (blue).

I've created the 2 (red and green) canvasses and those canvasses move around.

but coding the blue line i'm getting stuck.  I want to code a line between 2 frames that are moving around. the line must always be connected no matter how far apart the frames are from eachother. So I was wondering if this is even possible with tkinter or ttk?

below a small illustartion of what I've got in mind.

[image: Small illustation]

Comment: Yes, it's possible, if you use a `tkinter.Canvas`. You can also add text to the canvas, so if you wanted to put text in the frames you could do that.

Comment: I've got the canvas frames (red and green) in my root canvas ready with text and all. but i'm strugeling with the line(blue part) to create that so that mine canvas frames are connected.

Comment: Do you need the frames to move around? Could you be more specific as to what the error is? It looks in the image like it's working fine. What do you want it to do that it isn't doing?

Comment: When you say "frame" are you speaking of the tkinter `Frame` widget, or a canvas rectangle?

Comment: Also, if they are canvas objects, are they filled in or could they be filled in?

Comment: as Sylvester suggested I've updated the question. Rushed the question a bit.

Comment: The question is still not clear. You mention frames and canvases, but it's not clear if you're wanting to connect rectangles or `Frame` widgets.

Comment: updated the question. hope it is clear. If possible I want to code a line between 2 frames that are moving around. the line must always be connected no matter how far apart the frames are from eachother

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The canvas doesn't provide a way to connect objects, but you can simulate it by simply drawing the line between the two objects. If the rectangles are filled in, you can draw a line from the center point of one to the center point of the other. You can then lower the lines in the stacking order so that the part of the line behind the rectangles won't show.

If you give the line a tag that can be computed, whenever either one of the rectangles move you can also recompute the coordinates of the line that connects them.

```
import tkinter as tk
import random

def connect(a,b):
    # compupte the tag, then delete any existing lines
    # between these two objects
    tag = f"connector_{a}_{b}"
    canvas.delete(tag)

    ax0, ay0, ax1, ay1 = canvas.coords(a)
    bx0, by0, bx1, by1 = canvas.coords(b)

    x0 = (ax0 + ax1) / 2
    y0 = (ay0 + ay1) / 2

    x1 = (bx0 + bx1) / 2
    y1 = (by0 + by1) / 2

    # create the line, then lower it below all other
    # objects
    line_id = canvas.create_line(x0, y0, x1, y1, fill="blue", width=4, tags=(tag,))
    canvas.tag_lower(line_id)

def move_rectangles():
    canvas.move(f1, random.randint(-50, 50), 0)
    canvas.move(f2, 0, random.randint(-50, 50))
    connect(f1, f2)

root = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=400, height=500, background="white")
button = tk.Button(root, text="Move rectangles", command=move_rectangles)

button.pack(side="top")
canvas.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

f1 = canvas.create_rectangle(50,50, 150, 250, outline="red", fill="white", width=4)
f2 = canvas.create_rectangle(250,100, 350, 350, outline="green", fill="white", width=4)

connect(f1, f2)


root.mainloop()
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: copied the code and changed it a bit. I see why I couldn't manage to get this working. the line is a canvas with a small width instead of a line. thax Bryan Oakley